# Codeigniter image upload

Tags: codeigniter, upload, image-manipulation, form-submit

I am wanting to allow my user to upload an image, using a form. In the same form I want to display the image that has been uploaded. Is this is possible to do without actually submitting all the form?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible (as far as I know, you can't display a client-side image). You can use ajax though to update it (and maybe even force the form to submit?) Then at least the data refreshes without the page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any number of flash or AJAX image uploaders to accomplish this.